# VMs unable to join domain controller on Hyper-V host

Tags: hyper-v

I've setup a Hyper-V machine running Server 2008 R2.  it's configured as a DC for contoso.com (for example).

I'm trying to get a virtual machine to join the Domain, but it says it cannot find a domain controller for that domain.  The virtual can ping the host (servername.contoso.com) ok.

Any thoughs?

thanks.

Comment: You should try http://www.serverfault.com

Answer (score 3):

Check the steps from http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/virtualmachingmgrhyperv/thread/3687199f-1ddf-4b91-b40f-6302ddd840a0

Maybe they are similar in your case.

Comment: In my case I had the VM DNS pointing to both domain controller, and my home network router. Even though domain controller was first in the list I still had this problem. Only went away when I removed the router as secondary DNS. Thanks a million, this was driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

I have installed hyper-v with 2 virtual machines. I set one as DC and the other one i wanted to use it to test exchange. I was having issue with joining. I de-selected the IPv6 option on the VM and that resolved the issue.